# Rails 4: Smarter CSV will not add single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import

I am trying to use [SmarterCSV](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) to add entries into my database and it is working fine except for one field.  I have a `start` field and a `end` field, both of which are of the `date` type, and when I try to add a CSV with both, only 1 value gets inserted.

**test.csv**

```
user_id,regular,overtime,doubletime,sick,vacation,holiday,personal,other,start,end
100,5.28,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,6/1/2016,6/30/2016
```

**import function**

```
def self.import(file)
    options = { :downcase_header => false }
    n = SmarterCSV.process(file.tempfile, options) do |array|
        array.first[:employee_id] = Employee.find_by(user_id: array.first[:user_id]).id
        Timecard.create( array.first )
    end
end
```

...results in

```
INSERT INTO "timecards" ("user_id", "regular", "overtime", "doubletime", "sick", "vacation", "holiday", "personal", "other", "start", "employee_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 100], ["regular", 5.28], ["overtime", 0.0], ["doubletime", 0.0], ["sick", 0.0], ["vacation", 0.0], ["holiday", 0.0], ["personal", 0.0], ["other", 0.0], ["start", "2016-01-06"], ["employee_id", 18], ["created_at", "2016-07-08 19:00:06.124457"], ["updated_at", "2016-07-08 19:00:06.124457"]]
```

...and my `:end` should be permitted:

```
def timecard_params
    params.require(:timecard).permit(:start, :end, :employee, :user_id, :regular, :overtime, :doubletime, :sick, :vacation, :holiday, :personal, :other)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it was a date formatting issue.  `6/1/2016` works because it believes the date is Jan 6, 2016, `6/30/2016` does not work because in the DD/MM/YYYY format, `6/30/2016` is an invalid date.